# Are FSEvents available in IOS?

Tags: ios

In my app I need to be able to monitor a directory for file changes (add/ delete).  I have read about FSEvents being available in IOS 5 but can find no additional information on this. Does anyone know are they available ? and if so are there any examples available ?

Comment: hey, did you get any answer to this?

Comment: I didn't use FSEvents they weren't supported - I used kevent instead answered my own question below

Comment: thanks for replying, I know about kevent, but problem with kevent is that it does not monitor subdirectories.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up with a FileMonitor class that used kevents

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


        @protocol FileMonitorDelegate <NSObject>
        @required
        -(void) dirChanged:(NSString*) aDirName;
        @end

 @interface FileMonitor : NSObject

    - (void) monitorDir:(NSString*) aDir delegate:(id<FileMonitorDelegate>) aDelegate;

    @end
```

And the implementation

```
#import <fcntl.h>
#import <unistd.h>
#import <sys/event.h>

#import "FileMonitor.h"
#import "LogMacros.h"


@interface FileMonitor ()

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CFFileDescriptorRef _fileDes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* fns;

@end

    @implementation FileMonitor

    static int                  _dirFD;
    static CFFileDescriptorRef  _fileDes;
    static id<FileMonitorDelegate> _delegate;
    static NSString *_watchedDir;

    static void KQCallback(CFFileDescriptorRef kqRef, CFOptionFlags callBackTypes, void *info){

        LOG(@"KQCallback called !!");
        if(_delegate){
            [_delegate dirChanged:_watchedDir];
        }

        // Pull the native FD around which the CFFileDescriptor was wrapped
        int kq = CFFileDescriptorGetNativeDescriptor(_fileDes);
        if (kq < 0){
            return;
        }

        // If we pull a single available event out of the queue, assume the directory was updated
        struct kevent event;
        struct timespec timeout = {0, 0};
        if (kevent(kq, NULL, 0, &event, 1, &timeout) == 1){
            if( _delegate ){
                [_delegate dirChanged:_watchedDir];
            }else{
                LOG_ERROR(@"Callback with NO delegate set");
            }
        }

        // issue callback request
        CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(_fileDes, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack);
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark View lifecycle


    - (void) monitorDir:(NSString*) aDir delegate:(id<FileMonitorDelegate>) aDelegate{
        ASSERT(aDir);
        ASSERT(aDelegate);
        _watchedDir = aDir;
        _delegate = aDelegate;

        NSError *error;

        self.fns = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:aDir error:&error];
        LOG_IF_NSERROR(error);
        [self startMonitor];
    }

    - (void)startMonitor {
        // One ping only
        if (_fileDes != NULL){
            LOG_ERROR(@"kernel queue was null");
            return;
        }

        // Open an event-only file descriptor associated with the directory
        int dirFD = open([ _watchedDir fileSystemRepresentation], O_EVTONLY);
        if (dirFD < 0) {
            LOG_ERROR(@"could not open file descriptor");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new kernel event queue
        int kq = kqueue();
        if (kq < 0){
            LOG_ERROR(@"could not open kernel queue");
            close(dirFD);
            return;
        }

        // Set up a kevent to monitor
        struct kevent eventToAdd;                   // Register an (ident, filter) pair with the kqueue
        eventToAdd.ident  = dirFD;                  // The object to watch (the directory FD)
        eventToAdd.filter = EVFILT_VNODE;           // Watch for certain events on the VNODE spec'd by ident
        eventToAdd.flags  = EV_ADD | EV_CLEAR;      // Add a resetting kevent
        eventToAdd.fflags = NOTE_WRITE;             // The events to watch for on the VNODE spec'd by ident (writes)
        eventToAdd.data   = 0;                      // No filter-specific data
        eventToAdd.udata  = NULL;                   // No user data

        // Add a kevent to monitor
        if (kevent(kq, &eventToAdd, 1, NULL, 0, NULL)){
            close(kq);
            close(dirFD);
            return;
        }

        // Wrap a CFFileDescriptor around a native FD
        CFFileDescriptorContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
        _fileDes = CFFileDescriptorCreate(NULL,     // Use the default allocator
                                        kq,         // Wrap the kqueue
                                        true,       // Close the CFFileDescriptor if kq is invalidated
                                        KQCallback, // Fxn to call on activity
                                        &context);  // Supply a context to set the callback's "info" argument
        if (_fileDes == NULL){
            close(kq);
            close(dirFD);
            return;
        }

        // Spin out a pluggable run loop source from the CFFileDescriptorRef
        // Add it to the current run loop, then release it
        CFRunLoopSourceRef rls = CFFileDescriptorCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, _fileDes, 0);
        if (rls == NULL){
            CFRelease(_fileDes); _fileDes = NULL;
            close(kq);
            close(dirFD);
            return;
        }
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), rls, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
        CFRelease(rls);

        // Store the directory FD for later closing
        _dirFD = dirFD;

        // issue callback request
        CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(_fileDes, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack);
    }

    - (void)stopMonitor{
        if (_fileDes)
        {
            close(_dirFD);
            CFFileDescriptorInvalidate(_fileDes);
            CFRelease(_fileDes);
            _fileDes = NULL;
        }
    }

    - (void)restartMonitor{
        [self stopMonitor];
        [self startMonitor];
    }

    - (void)dealloc{
        [self stopMonitor];
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out the higher-level (and more powerful than FSEvents anyway) NSFileCoordinator and NSFilePresenter protocols.

**NSFilePresenter:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

**NSFileCoordinator:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/Reference/Reference.html

There was a WWDC session 'Taking Advantage of File Coordination' giving an overview of the API in 2011, the video of which is worth checking out.

Comment: Note. `NSFilePresenter` is known as buggy (doesn't fire many delegate events) from 2010 and still does. There's no move to fix this.